# How to get better table alias names for SQL statements created by Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

Is it possible to control which table alias names Entity Framework uses for the SQL statements it creates? For example, instead of

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extend1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extend2] ON [Extend1].[CustomerId] = [Extend2].[Id]
WHERE [Extent2].[Name] = 'xyz'
```

I'd like to get

```
SELECT [order].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [order]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Customers] AS [customer] ON [order].[CustomerId] = [customer].[Id]
WHERE [customer].[Name] = 'xyz'
```

or something similar, as long as I don't have to remember which extend number is which table. Of course in this simple sample it's no problem, but in queries where you have `[Extend1]` to `[Extend7]` it's really getting complicated.

Comment: If you're spending a lot of time looking at machine generated queries, there's something very wrong and it's not the names that are being applied.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't spend "a lot of time" with them, but during development I need to look at them to know which indices I need to create on my tables. And sometimes little changes in Linq queries lead to far better SQL queries, but to know where to optimize I have to see (and understand) the created queries.

Comment: +1 We profile all major queries including verifying the emitted sql. Having better alias names would be very useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`IDbCommandInterceptor`](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interception) and override the [`CommandText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I just created a very simple logic to replace the alias name using regular expression.

Following code

```
var query = (from f1 in db.Foos
            where f1.ParentFooId == null
            join f2 in db.Foos on f1.FooId equals f2.ParentFooId
            select f2).ToArray();
```

by default will become something like

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[FooId] AS [FooId], 
    [Extent2].[FooId] AS [FooId1], 
    [Extent2].[FooName] AS [FooName], 
    [Extent2].[ParentFooId] AS [ParentFooId], 
    [Extent2].[ParentFoo_FooId] AS [ParentFoo_FooId]
    FROM  [dbo].[Foos] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Foos] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[FooId] = [Extent2].[ParentFooId]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ParentFooId] IS NULL
go
```

and then I intercepted the command text on `ReaderExcecuting`.

```
public void ReaderExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
{
    var aliasLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var tableLookup = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    var text = command.CommandText;
    // Looking something like "[dbo].[Foos] AS [Extent1]"
    var pattern = @"\[dbo\]\.\[([\w\d]*)\] AS \[(Extent\d*)\]";
    var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);
    foreach(Match m in matches)
    {
        if (m.Groups.Count == 3)
        {
            var tableName = m.Groups[1].Value;
            var aliasName = m.Groups[2].Value;

            var replacement = tableName;
            if (tableLookup.ContainsKey(tableName)) replacement += tableLookup[tableName]++;
            else tableLookup.Add(tableName, 2);

            aliasLookup.Add(aliasName, replacement);
        }
    });

    foreach(var pair in aliasLookup)
    {
        var oldAliasName = string.Format("[{0}]", pair.Key);
        var newAliasName = string.Format("[{0}]", pair.Value);
        command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace(oldAliasName, newAliasName);
    }
}
```

The result would look like

```
SELECT 
    [Foos].[FooId] AS [FooId], 
    [Foos2].[FooId] AS [FooId1], 
    [Foos2].[FooName] AS [FooName], 
    [Foos2].[ParentFooId] AS [ParentFooId], 
    [Foos2].[ParentFoo_FooId] AS [ParentFoo_FooId]
    FROM  [dbo].[Foos] AS [Foos]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Foos] AS [Foos2] ON [Foos].[FooId] = [Foos2].[ParentFooId]
    WHERE [Foos].[ParentFooId] IS NULL
go
```

This is just giving you the idea how to do it, the logic hasn't been tested for complex query and it should be used only for debugging.

Comment: Nice, thanks! But is there a reason why you use `regex.Replace` without actually replacing anything instead of iterating over `regex.Matches`?

Comment: @cremor, I only know to use regex.Replace, if it's working with regex.Matches, feel free to edit my answer..

Comment: how to implement and override this method of entity framework?